# Login failure in android using custom API

Tags: android, json, postman

I'm currently occurring a login failure. I tried many different method, and none works. I think it's something related to some connection problem, the `onResponse` method doesn't works. Kindly help me to figure out this issue.

Thanks

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), URL + "On Response" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), URL + "On Response" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("email", "kenchivas1998@gmail.com");
                    hashMap.put("password", "nguyenduclai1998");
                    return super.getParams();
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
```

And this is ErrorLog

```
Process: com.example.e_learning, PID: 28955
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_learning-Mgs3GV9Uzd2qvvHQT2xjJA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.e_learning-Mgs3GV9Uzd2qvvHQT2xjJA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109) 
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97) 
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

enter code here
    enter code here

Comment: Can you please post your stacktrace as well? It would be so much faster. Also try googling with stacktrace please, not the problem in a verbal fashion.

Comment: Never show a clean password like this in any forum. Also try to give some more detail with the error logs. It will help to give a better answer.

Comment: have you tried your api in POSTMAN.? also make sure internet permission is added in manifest.

Comment: My POSTMAN and INTERNET does work :( !

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting sdk 28 or up, you may need to add this to your manifest:

```
 <uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library